# Underfined in a prototype

Tags: javascript

I changed the Human Prototype and now I am still getting undefined when I check a property:

```
function Human() {
    this.name = "Default Human";
    this.age = "Default Age";
    this.height = 122;
}

function humanExtend() {
    this.address = "Updated Address Sun";
    this.power = "ShowBoat";
}

var banmeet = new Human();
console.log(banmeet.name);

Human.prototype = humanExtend;

var bradPitt = new Human();
console.log(bradPitt.power);
```

But I am getting an **undefined for bradPitt.power.**.

Why is that?

Comment: Don't tag your Javascript questions Java.

Comment: Prototype is for **methods**, not properties

Comment: this is not how prototype works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have been assigned instance of HumanExtend as below -

```js
function Human() {
    this.name = "Default Human";
    this.age = "Default Age";
    this.height = 122;


}
function humanExtend() {
    this.address = "Updated Address Sun";
    this.power = "ShowBoat";

}

var banmeet = new Human();
console.log(banmeet.name);


//Assign instance of HumanExtend here
Human.prototype = new humanExtend();


var bradPitt = new Human();
console.log(bradPitt.power);
```

Comment: @marc-andre-jiacarrini - please go through below url for better understanding of prototypal inheritance 
http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

Comment: By assigning a **new** `prototype`, that will work for newly created objects (like `bradPitt`), but it will not be applied to previous instances (`banmeet` will not receive the new prototype).